# What does this css selector syntax mean?

Tags: html, css

I have seen the syntax:

```
ul#nav li a
{
}
```

And im not really sure what it means, is it the same as saying:

```
#nav ul li a
```

?

I guess I dont really understand what it means to have an element type before an id selector with no space...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ul#nav` will apply to `<ul id="nav">`

whereas:

`#nav ul` will apply to any `<ul>` **within the** `<tag id="nav">`

Comment: `#nav ul` will not apply to every `<ul>`, it will apply to every `<ul>` within any `<tag id="nav">`

Answer (score 6):

`ul#nav li a` will select:

- `<a>` elements...
- That are within a `<li>` element...
- That are within a `<ul>` with `id` attribute equal to `nav`.

It won't select descendants of any element that is not a `<ul>`, even if it's `id` is `nav`.

It is a bit redundant, as ids are unique. For all practical purposes, `#nav li a` will do.

---

> Is it the same as saying: `#nav ul li a`?

Note that `#nav ul li a` is not the same, this would select the `a` within an `li` if it is a descendant `ul` *of* another element with id `nav`.

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a>This would be selected</a></li>
  </ul>
<div>

<ul id="nav">
  <li><a>This would not be selected</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

> I guess I dont really understand what it means to have an element type before an id selector with no space...

You can combine multiple selectors on one element. Here's a silly example:

```
a#message.error.active[rel="foobar"]:hover {}
```

This will select an `<a>` element with `id="message"` when it is hovered, only if it has the class `error`, as well as the class `active`, and it's `rel` attribute is `foobar`.

---

The basics are explained here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: +1 for saying that it is redundant because `#id` are supposed to be unique

Comment: "supposed to be" being the key - I see a lot of people around here who are not aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

That selects an anchor inside a list item inside an un-ordered list that has the ID 'nav'

So

```
<ul id='nav'>
    <li>
        <a href='test.com'>Test</a>
    </li>
<ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href='test.com'>Test</a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

It would match the first Anchor, not the second.

It's not the same as the second, if it works at all it'd only match where the UL had a parent with an ID of 'nav'.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that while the `tag#id_name` syntax is redundant because id's are unique, that syntax is useful when dealing with classes.

`ul.nav li { }` can be used to differentiate between multiple tags of the same class.

Like this:

```
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>Stuff</li>
  </ul>
  <ol class="nav">
    <li>First Item</li>
  </ol>
```

`ul.nav li { }` will affect "Stuff" while
`ol.nav li { }` will affect "First Item."

Comment: There are definitely use cases for `tag#id_name` as well, but they are fairly rare and can usually be avoided. I'm happy you pointed out how this can be useful with classes for example. Also: Welcome to the site! Nice first post.